# C# SharePoint 2013 Modal Window Style Formatting will not print

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, printing

**Problem:** 
SharePoint 2013 Application Page in a modal window has **color formatting that will not print**.  I can see the style codes in 'View Source'.  When I print, or do a 'print preview' - all formatting is removed.

**More Information:**

- I open the application Page in my C#.NET SharePoint solution by activating
  the following script command when a 'print' button is clicked:
      ***SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);***
- A "printer friendly" modal view of a GridView displays - all styles are visible.  Style code/formatting is also visible in 'view source'.
- I have a print button on this modal page which activates a
  'window.print()' script.
- When that button is pressed, the printer dialog opens.
- I can see the report in printPreview and I can print the report...but
  all styles are stripped.

**Question:**
How can I print this view (or any page with only a gridView and some text in SharePoint) with style formatting?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found a way to make this work.  The style sheet needs the @media directive....but also, I had to add this:

-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;